# Can't read international characters from files

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, character-encoding, internationalization

I am trying to read portuguese characters from files, and keep getting into problems.

I have the following C# code (for testing purposes):

```
var streamReader = new StreamReader("file.txt");

while (streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
{
  var buffer = new char[1];
  streamReader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  Console.Write(buffer[0]);
}
```

It reads each character in the file and then outputs it to the console. 
The file contains the following: "cãsa". 
The output in the console is: "c?sa".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at the `StreamReader` constructors. You can specify the encoding.

Comment: If you execute Console.Write("cãsa"), how do you see it written to the console?

Comment: You'll need to know (find out) what encoding was used to write the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the file using the correct encoding - by default the file will be read as UTF-8, if that's not the right encoding, you will get such issues.

In this example, I am using an constructor overload that takes an encoding, in this case `UnicodeEncoding`, which is UTF-16:

```
using(var streamReader = new StreamReader("file.txt", Encoding.UnicodeEncoding))
{
    while (streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
    {
      var buffer = new char[1];
      streamReader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
      Console.Write(buffer[0]);
    }
}
```

In this example, I am using codepage 860, corresponding to Portuguese:

```
using(var streamReader = new StreamReader("file.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(860)))
{
    while (streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
    {
      var buffer = new char[1];
      streamReader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
      Console.Write(buffer[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @PeterEvjan - These were just _examples_. You need to find out what encoding the text file was saved in and use the exact same one for reading it. As you can imagine, I don't have that information.